# how prove $n! \mid \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(2^n-2^k) :\forall n \in \mathbb N$?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

how prove $$n! \mid \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(2^n-2^k)  :\forall n\in \mathbb N  $$

Thanks in advance

Comment: A cute way to do this, not the intended way, is to find a group with cardinality the RHS and show that it contains $S_n$ as a subgroup.

Comment: You can consider the this product to be the number of ordered bases $v_1,\dots,v_n$ of the vector space $\mathbb F_2^n$. Then the symmetric group $S_n$ acts on this set in an interesting fashion.

Comment: Hah, my comment is essentially the same as @QiaochuYuan, slightly obscured.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: ithink its good idea but its so hard

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: hi can you explain more i don't understand completely

Comment: Do you know what I mean when I say $\mathbb F_2^n$ and "bases?" It is a bit difficult to go into more details without those definitions.

Comment: @Thomas Andrewsi: know definition of base and vector space but i don't know whats $\mathbb F_2^n$?

Comment: $\mathbb F_2$ is the field with $2$ elements, also written $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z_2$. So $\mathbb F_2^n$ is the $n$-dimenensional vector space over this field.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews:  is$\mathbb F_2$ free group of order 2?

Comment: No, see previous comment. @MaisamHedyelloo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A direct proof would use remembering how we proved that the highest power of a prime $p$ that divides $n!$ is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor$$

The same logic can show that the highest power of an odd prime that divides the right side is at least:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^{k}-p^{k-1}}\right\rfloor$$

Essentially, this is because $p^k$ divides $2^m-1$ when $m$ is a multiple of $p^k-p^{k-1}=\phi(p^k)$.

Since $p^k-p^{k-1} < p^k$, each term is as least as big as the associated term from the sum for $n!$

Then you just have to deal with the case $p=2$.

Comment: A nearly identical argument appears in section 2.3 [here](http://www.ias.ac.in/resonance/December2010/p1111-1121.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

This is the nice, scenic route Qiaochu mentions in the comments. It is not entirely obvious to me that this is not the "intended" answer for this, as it is tagged as a contest problem.

Let ${\bf F}_q$ denote the (unique) [finite field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) with exactly $q=p^s$ elements ($p$ a prime number). The invertible linear maps on the vector space ${\bf F}_q^n$ are in bijection with the ordered $n$-tuples of linearly independent column vectors from ${\bf F}_q^n$. The number of these (so, in effect the size of ${\rm GL}_n({\bf F}_q)$) may be counted combinatorially, directly.

For the first vector, we can choose anything that is nonzero, which makes for $q^n-1$ possible choices. For the second, we can choose anything that is not in the linear span of the first, and the linear span of the first vector is a one-dimensional subspace (so in particular it has $q$ elements), hence there are $q^n-q$ possible choices for the second vector. We may continue in this way for

$$|{\rm GL}_n({\bf F}_q)|=(q^n-1)(q^n-q)(q^n-q^2)\cdots(q^n-q^{n-1})=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(q^n-q^k).$$

Another way of expressing this is as $(q-1)^nq^{(n-1)n/2}[n]_q!$ using the [$q$-factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-Factorial.html).

The [symmetric group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) $S_n$ is realized directly as a subgroup of ${\rm GL}_n({\bf F}_q)$ via [permutation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix), and so by [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) it follows that for any prime power $q$,

$$n!\mid\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(q^n-q^k).$$

This case is in particular $q=2$.

A mostly equivalent line of reasoning is seen through [group actions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) in Thomas' comment: the symmetric group $S_n$ acts on the set of $n$-tuples of linearly independent vectors of ${\bf F}_q^n$ through permutating the coordinates; in none of these $n$-tuples are any two coordinates the same, so every stabilizer is trivial, so every orbit has size $|S_n|=n!$ (by [orbit-stabilizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem_and_Burnside.27s_lemma)), so that the whole space of $n$-tuples under consideration has size a multiple of $n!$ as it is a disjoint union of orbits of size $n!$.

This is pretty much letting the subgroup $S_n$ act on ${\rm GL}_n({\bf F}_q)$ via right-multiplication by inverses.

Comment: IIRC this is a high school contest problem, so the intended solution shouldn't use quite so much abstract algebra.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still wondering whether it can be proven with a more direct counting argument of some sort. I think my answer below generalizes to $q$ that is not a prime power, unless I'm mistaken, so maybe there is an argument that doesn't use fields? I don't like my answer - it is not very illuminating. @QiaochuYuan

Comment: Also, while tagged as a contest problem, the OP calls himself an undergraduate, so it could be a college level contest... @QiaochuYuan